# AJAX call not working with &#?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, callback

I am having a problem with JQuery ajax. I am making a call to an aspx file. But here is the strange part, if i have the characters &# after one another, then it doesn't work. It works with everything (i think) else. But just those 2 characters after each other. They work solo, so like just the # or just &.

This is the code that i am using:

```
function CreateNewItem() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'List.aspx',
    data: ({ Callback: "CreateNewItem", ListID: currentList, ItemSubject: $('#editContentTitle').val(), ItemText: $('#editContentBox').val(), Author: author }),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (newItem) {
        if (newItem.status == "success") {
            $('#ItemBoxDiv').append(GetItemHTML(newItem.itemID, newItem.itemSubject, newItem.itemText, author, newItem.itemPosted, newItem.itemCompleted));
            RestartAccordion();
        }
        else
            ErrorOccured('The message could not be created due to the following reason\\n' + newItem.errorMessage);
    },
    failed: function (data) {
        ErrorOccured('The item could not be created, an unknown error occured and the ajax request/response was incorrect');
    }
});
}
```

So when i use a normal text i get back a JSON object with the variable status set to success. When i skip entering for instance the author, i get a JSON object back with the variable status set to failed. But when i try &# i get a null back, the aspx page is not even hit. I've done extensive testing with the aspx page but that one works, the method is never invoked when those 2 characters are posted.

I found this problem when i tried to save a forum address:

Forum.aspx?g=posts&t=194&#post1536

Any ideas?

Comment: provide the code in list.aspx that receives the json message and generates the return value

Comment: Meaningless since it's not even getting to that point. It returns null from some were else and i have been through the entire List.aspx.cs file for possible errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecode all your data before passing to server.

```
data: ({ 
    Callback: "CreateNewItem", 
    ListID: currentList, 
    ItemSubject: encodeURIComponent($('#editContentTitle').val()), 
    ItemText: encodeURIComponent($('#editContentBox').val()), 
    Author: author 
}),
```

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

You get a null back because #post1536 in the context of a URI is an internal page anchor.

If the #post1536 is an ID indicator, then you should try changing it to be &postId=1536.

I'm not familiar with the way you're sending data. According to the API for jQuery.ajax() this method of sending data though requires a synchronous (user blocking) request. I've always sent the params in a string or hash. Also, your callback function was the same function as the one executing the ajax. You wouldn't need to do this since "success" is your callback. Try something like the following:

```
var params = "ListId=" + currentList + "&ItemSubject=" + $('#editContentTitle').val() + "&ItemText=" + $('#editContentBox').val() + "&Author=" + author;
$.ajax({
    url: 'List.aspx',
    data: params,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (newItem) {
        if (newItem.status == "success") {
            $('#ItemBoxDiv').append(GetItemHTML(newItem.itemID, newItem.itemSubject, newItem.itemText, author, newItem.itemPosted, newItem.itemCompleted));
            RestartAccordion();
        }
        else
            ErrorOccured('The message could not be created due to the following reason\\n' + newItem.errorMessage);
    },
    failed: function (data) {
        ErrorOccured('The item could not be created, an unknown error occured and the ajax request/response was incorrect');
    }
});
```

Comment: The ajax script that i am running takes a text and stores it in the database. I have a textbox were i just enter text that then gets saved. Not just forum post links, could be anything. How can i work around that problem? I want it to be able to save everything.

Comment: I've provided some clarification that might help.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to send a server request with a hash tag, it only has relevance on the client. I'd suggest stripping it out before the request.

A theory for why it's happening. If the url you're making the request to is the same as the url you're currently on, the browser may not attempt to make the request as it would assume you're trying to access a bookmark within the current page. Just a guess though.

Example of change hash tag to query string.

```
var url = "Forum.aspx?g=posts&t=194&#post1536".replace("#post", "post="); // returns Forum.aspx?g=posts&t=194&post=1536
```

Rich

Comment: It is the same page. How can i strip it out. See the comment i made by hal10001.

Comment: If the url you're working with is `Forum.aspx?g=posts&t=194&#post1536` and you would like to send the post id to the server, I'd use the replace method. I've included an example above.

Comment: The problem is that it's the textbox $('#editContentBox').val() that the link is in. I don't know what links/text that i will post in the future. I need an universal converter. Next time i might be something else like data.aspx?hello&#. If JQuery can't even send a simple text string, then whats it good for? I mean, i am not interfering with the URL "List.aspx". It's just plain text.